# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\binom{2n}{n} (H_{2n} - H_n)}{4^n (2n - 1)^2} = 2 + \frac{3\pi}{2} \log(2) - 2G - \pi$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, summation, harmonic-numbers

Show that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\binom{2n}{n} (H_{2n} - H_n)}{4^n (2n - 1)^2} = 2 + \frac{3\pi}{2} \log(2) - 2G - \pi$$

**My try :**
We know that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n} (H_{2n} - H_{n}) t^n = - \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - 4t}} \log\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{1 - 4t}}{2}\right)$$

In particular we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n} \frac{(H_{2n} - H_{n})}{4^n} t^{2n} = - \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - t^2}} \log\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{1 - t^2}}{2}\right)$$....(1)

Next, dividing both sides of (1) by $t ^ 2$ and then integrating from 0 to 2, we get

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n} \frac{(H_{2n} - H_{n})}{4^n (2n - 1)} x^{2n - 1} = - \int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{t^2 \sqrt{1 - t^2}} \log\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{1 - t^2}}{2}\right) \, dt$$

Making the change of variable $t=sin(\theta)$ in
$$J = \int \frac{1}{t^2 \sqrt{1 - t^2}} \log\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{1 - t^2}}{2}\right) \, dt$$

$$J = \int \frac{1}{\sin^2 \theta \cos \theta} \log\left(\frac{1 + \cos \theta}{2}\right) \cos \theta \, d\theta$$

Comment: You have a factor $1/(2n-1)^2$ in the expression to compute not $1/(2n-1)$. That's meaning you need to integrate twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n\ge 1}
 \binom{2n}{n} 
 \frac{(H_{2n} - H_{n})}{4^n (2n - 1)} x^{2n - 1} 
&= 
- \int_{0}^{x} 
\frac{1}{t^2 \sqrt{1 - t^2}} 
\log\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{1 - t^2}}{2}\right) \, dt
\\
\sum_{n\ge 1}
 \binom{2n}{n} 
 \frac{(H_{2n} - H_{n})}{4^n (2n - 1)} x^{2n - 2} 
&= 
- \frac 1x
\int_{0}^{x} 
\frac{1}{t^2 \sqrt{1 - t^2}} 
\log\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{1 - t^2}}{2}\right) \, dt
\\
\\
\sum_{n\ge 1}
 \binom{2n}{n} 
 \frac{(H_{2n} - H_{n})}{4^n (2n - 1)^2}
 \phantom{x^{2n - 2} }
&= 
- 
\int_0^1
\frac {dx}x
\int_{0}^{x} 
\frac{1}{t^2 \sqrt{1 - t^2}} 
\log\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{1 - t^2}}{2}\right) \, dt
\\
&=
-
\iint_{0\le t\le x\le 1}
\frac 1x
\frac{1}{t^2 \sqrt{1 - t^2}} 
\log\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{1 - t^2}}{2}\right) \, dx\, dt
\\
&=
-
\int_0^1
\frac{1}{t^2 \sqrt{1 - t^2}} 
\log\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{1 - t^2}}{2}\right)\, dt
\int_t^1\frac{dx}x
\\
&=
\int_0^1
\frac{1}{t^2 \sqrt{1 - t^2}} 
\log\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{1 - t^2}}{2}\right)
\log t
\; dt
\\
&\qquad\text{Substitution: $t=\sin 2u$}
\\
&=
\int_0^{\pi/4}
\frac{1}{\sin^2 2u \color{gray}{\cos 2u}} 
\log\left(\frac{1 + \cos 2u}{2}\right)
\log (\sin 2u)
\cdot 2\color{gray}{\cos 2u}\; du
\\
&=
\underbrace{
\int_0^{\pi/4}
\frac 1{4\sin^2 u \cos^2u} 
\log\left(\cos ^2 u\right)
\log (2\sin u\cos u)
\; 2\; du}_{:=J}
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Let us compute this last integral $J$.

In it, it is easy to pass from $\log(\cos u)$ to $\log(\cos^2 u)$ back and forth, similarly for the passage between $\log(\sin u)$ and $\log(\sin^2 u)$, if needed. We split the last integral in three corresponding integrals $J_1,J_2,J_3$ to the relation
$$
\log (2\sin u\cos u)
=\log(2) 
+\log(\sin u) + \log(\cos u)\ .
$$
Two of the resulted integrals are more or less straightforward:
$$
\begin{aligned}
J_1
&:=\int_0^{\pi/4}
\frac 1{4\sin^2 u \cos^2u} 
\log\left(\cos ^2 u\right)
\log (2)
\; 2\; du
\\
&=-2\log 2\int_0^{\pi/4}
(\cot 2u)'
\log\left(\cos u\right)\; du
\\
&=
-2\log 2
\Bigg[
\cot 2u\cdot
\log\left(\cos u\right)\Bigg]_0^{\pi/4}
-2\log 2
\int_0^{\pi/4}
\cot 2u\cdot
\tan u\; du
\\
&=
-\log 2
\int_0^{\pi/4}
(1-\tan^2 u)\; du
=-\log2\left(\frac \pi2-1\right)\ ,
\\[2mm]
J_2
&:=\int_0^{\pi/4}
\frac 1{4\sin^2 u \cos^2u} 
\log\left(\cos ^2 u\right)
\log (\cos u)
\; 2\; du
\\
&=-2\int_0^{\pi/4}
(\cot 2u)'
\log^2(\cos u)\; du
\\
&=
-2
\Bigg[
\cot 2u\cdot
\log^2(\cos u)\Bigg]_0^{\pi/4}
-2
\int_0^{\pi/4}
\cot 2u\cdot
\tan u\cdot2\log(\cos u)\; du
\\
&=
-\int_0^{\pi/4}
2(1-\tan^2 u)\log(\cos u)\; du
=
-\int_0^{\pi/4}
2(2u-\tan u)'\log(\cos u)\; du
\\
&=\left(\frac \pi2-1\right)\log 2
-
2\int_0^{\pi/4}
(2u-\tan u)\tan u\; du
\\
&=\left(\frac \pi2-1\right)\log 2
-\left(2G -\frac\pi2\log 2\right)
+\left(2-\frac \pi2\right)
\\
&=(\pi-1)\log 2- 2G + 2-\frac \pi2
\ ,
\\[2mm]
J_3
&:=\int_0^{\pi/4}
\frac 1{4\sin^2 u \cos^2u} 
\log\left(\cos ^2 u\right)
\log (\sin u)
\; 2\; du
\\
&=-2\int_0^{\pi/4}
(\cot 2u)'
\log(\cos u)
\log(\sin u)
\; du
\\
&=
-2\Big[\cot 2u
\log(\cos u)
\log(\sin u)
\Big]_0^{\pi/4}
\\
&\qquad
- 2\int_0^{\pi/4}
\cot 2u
\cdot \tan u
\cdot\log(\sin u)
\; du
+ 2\int_0^{\pi/4}
\cot 2u
\cdot\log(\cos u)
\cdot\cot u
\; du
\\
&=
\underbrace{
\int_0^{\pi/4}
(\tan^2 u - 1)
\log(\sin u)
\; du}_{J_{31}}
+ 
\underbrace{
\int_0^{\pi/4}
(\cot^2 u - 1)
\log(\cos u)
\; du}_{J_{32}}
\\
&=J_{31} + J_{32}
\ ,
\\
&\qquad\text{ Substitution: $t=\tan u$, $u=\arctan t$, $du=dt/(1+t^2)$}
\\
J_{31}
&=
\frac 12
\int_0^1(t^2-1)\log\frac {t^2}{1+t^2}\;\frac{dt}{1+t^2}
\\
&=
\frac 12
\int_1^\infty
\frac {1-t^2}{t^2}\log\frac 1{1+t^2}
\;\frac{dt}{1+t^2}
\ ,
\\
J_{32}
&=
\frac 12
\int_0^1
\frac {1-t^2}{t^2}\log\frac 1{1+t^2}
\;\frac{dt}{1+t^2}\ ,\qquad\text{ so adding the two expressions:}
\\
J_3
&=
\frac 12
\int_0^\infty
\frac {t^2-1}{t^2(1+t^2)}
\log(1+t^2)
\;dt
\\
&=
\int_0^\infty
\frac 1{1+t^2}
\log(1+t^2)
\;dt
-
\frac 12
\underbrace{
\int_0^\infty
\frac 1{t^2}
\log(1+t^2)
\;dt}_{=\pi}\ , \text{ so let us consider}
\\
K(a) 
&= 
\int_0^\infty
\frac 1{1+t^2}
\log(a^2+t^2)
\;dt\ ,
\\
K'(a) &=
\int_0^\infty
\frac 1{1+t^2}\cdot \frac {2a}{a^2+t^2}
\;dt
=
\frac {2a}{a^2-1}
\int_0^\infty
\left(\frac 1{1+t^2}- \frac 1{a^2+t^2}\right)
\;dt
\\
&=\frac \pi{a+1}\ ,\\
K(a)&=\pi\log(a+1)\ ,\\
J_3&=K(1) -\frac \pi 2=\pi\log 2 -\frac \pi 2\ .
\\[5mm]
&\qquad\text{ Putting all together:}
\\[5mm]
J&=J_1+J_2+J_3
\\
&=
-\log2\left(\frac \pi2-1\right)
+\left((\pi-1)\log 2- 2G + 2-\frac \pi2\right)
+\left(\pi\log 2 -\frac \pi 2\right)
\\
&=\bbox[yellow]{\qquad\frac{3\pi}2\log 2 - 2G + 2-\pi\qquad}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: This solution is using the OP idea...

Comment: Thanks alot sir

Answer (score 2):

Using $$ H_{n} = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1 - u^n}{1-u} \, du $$ then the series
$$ S(t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n} \, \frac{H_{2n} - H_{n}}{4^n \, (2n-1)^2} \, t^n $$ leads to
$$ S(t) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{f(u \, t) - f(u^2 \, t)}{1-u} \, du, $$
where
$$ f(t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n} \, \frac{t^n}{4^n \, (2n-1)^2}. $$
It can be shown that
$$ f(t) = 1 - \sqrt{1-t} - \sqrt{t} \, \sin^{-1}(\sqrt{t}) $$
and leads to
$$ S(t) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sqrt{1-u^2 \, t} - \sqrt{1-u t} + \sqrt{t} \, (u \, \sin^{-1}(\sqrt{u^2 \, t}) - \sqrt{u} \, \sin^{-1}(\sqrt{u t}))}{1-u} \, du. $$
At this point the need to set $t = 1$ makes the calculations of the integrals possible. With this, then
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sqrt{1-u^2} - \sqrt{1-u}}{1-u} \, du &= \frac{\pi}{2} - 1 \\
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{u \, \sin^{-1}(u) - \sqrt{u} \, \sin^{-1}(\sqrt{u})}{1-u} \, du &= 3 - \frac{3 \pi}{2} + \frac{3 \pi}{2} \, \ln(2) - 2 \bf{G}.
\end{align}
Using the integrals shows that
$$ S(1) = 2 - \pi + \frac{3 \pi}{2} \, \ln(2) - 2 \bf{G}, $$
or
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n} \, \frac{H_{2n} - H_{n}}{4^n \, (2n-1)^2} = 2 - \pi + \frac{3 \pi}{2} \, \ln(2) - 2 \bf{G}, $$
where $\bf{G}$ is Catalan's constant.

Comment: Thanks alot sir